# Cursor is repeating first record forever

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code please. I'm simply trying to loop through a table with 2 records and get it to return 2 records. But as you may see in the image below, it keeps just repeating the first record (forever, until I hit cancel). Thank you

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON -- Improves performance by not returning number of rows affected

--General Variables
DECLARE @ImportGUID uniqueidentifier =NEWID() -- Declares and sets a new Unique number. Can be used to remove records at a later stage

--Cursor Variables
DECLARE @FirstNameVariable varchar(50)
DECLARE @SurnameVariable varchar(50)

PRINT 'Starting import ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), @ImportGUID); --just display this on the screen

--Declare the first cursor which will loop through a table collecting data
DECLARE NewPersonTableImportCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Firstname, Surname 
from dbo.A_NewPersonTable

--Open NewPersonTableImportCursor
OPEN NewPersonTableImportCursor
--Start looping through the data and updating the cursor variables with data from this cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM NewPersonTableImportCursor INTO @FirstNameVariable, @SurnameVariable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 --Fetch Status 0 means successfull so only proceed on those rows from source table that were successfull
BEGIN

PRINT @FirstNameVariable;
END
CLOSE NewPersonTableImportCursor
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to call `FETCH NEXT` again inside your loop, otherwise you will never actually fetch next. I'd be very wary of using a cursor though, in 99% if scenarios they are not the right tool for the job, and there is usually a better set based approach. If you **must** use a cursor, declare it in the most simple manner possible, i.e. if you are only moving forward, declare it with `FORWARD_ONLY`, if the data never changes declare it with `STATIC`, etc. More on this is here - https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options

Comment: You are not fetching the next result from the cursor inside the loop

Comment: @GarethD makes a very valid point here. Importing your data row by agonising row (RBAR) is going to be *extremely* slow. A Set based solution, or even a "set based cursor" (depending on the requirement) will almost certainly be far faster.

Comment: Here's and example of a set-based query to replace the cursor and loop, guessing at your final intent: `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Firstname, Surname) SELECT Firstname, Surname FROM dbo.A_NewPersonTable AS new WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Firstname, Surname FROM dbo.YourTable AS existing WHERE existing.Firstname = new.Firstname AND existing.Surname = new.Surname);`

Comment: Thank you. My end aim is to have a temp table with information that will populate several tables. A quick example - the temp table might have 3 columns (job number, employee, vehicle). The temp table has 10 records. For each record it will insert a new record into tblJobs and it will enter the employees ID. But if the employee doesn't exist (because we are just using their name) then it will also perform an insert on the tblEmployee as well before returning with the shiny new employeeID for entry into tblJobs. Would a cursor be the best use for that scenario? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `FETCH NEXT FROM NewPersonTableImportCursor INTO @FirstNameVariable, @SurnameVariable` before the end of the loop to get the next record

Comment: Thank you, so simple!